# Using one pot to control simultaneously different parameters

Tags: audio, analog, filter, potentiometer

First, please forgive my lack of knowledge, as i'm a beginner in the matter.

I'm looking for a way to control with one pot different parameters. In context, i'm trying to control a Filter Cutoff on two different channels. Later on i'll add options for more filter types, so a Dual-Gang Pot won't do me much good.
Also, i'm trying to do it as analog as possible. No MCUs in the mix.

I've been lurking everywhere to find such a method, and so far, aside from possibly a digital pot (which would require some digital circuitry, adding more components on a already tight space), i just can't find anything.

Could you possibly help me with this ?
Thanks

---

Now understanding it is virtually impossible, best choice for now is to use as many Double-Gang Pots as needed, in my case 6 of those. Thanks anyways for your help :)

Comment: Can you control both the band and the volume of a radio with a single knob?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Beside the point. Stereo volume control requires two different pots, or one Dual-Gang. That is unless delve into digital...

Comment: Irrational question. VTC as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** To "simultaneously" control two parameters? No.  To "sequentially" control two parameters?  Probably, if you use a switch to select between the channels - as long as you can tolerate needing to "refresh" the settings on each channel every so often.

**Long answer:** Almost anything is possible with the right circuit, but it's impossible to affect two variables independently with only one input.  You can use a switch or button as an additional input.

I'm assuming you have two outputs: filter cutoff on channel A, and filter cutoff on channel B.  I'm further assuming that the filter cutoffs can be controlled by a single analog voltage.  The first thing you need to do in the design process is envision exactly how a single pot would control both variables.  The most obvious method is to use a switch to select which variable is being controlled, and remember the setting of the other variable when it is not being controlled.

For now, let's remove the "no microcontroller" restriction so that we can get access to digital memory, which can retain information perfectly.  You could use a switch to select between the channels - when you switch from channel A to channel B, the current position of the pot is sampled, saved, and used to control the channel A cutoff.  The pot is then available to control channel B.

Now, back to the purely analog solution.  You need an analog memory cell - say, a capacitor followed by an op-amp voltage follower - for each channel.  You have a switch that connects the potentiometer to one capacitor or the other.  The cap charges to a specific voltage while it is connected to the potentiometer, then when the switch is moved, the capacitor holds that voltage.  You will need to make sure your cap self-discharge leakage and op-amp input leakage currents are extremely low to prevent the voltage from changing noticeably over whatever timeframe you expect to go between adjustments to each channel.  And you'll need to balance that against making sure the capacitance and pot resistance are small enough to avoid a noticeable delay when you turn the knob (buffering the pot with a 3rd voltage follower may help with that).

Getting your capacitor droop small enough is where things get interesting.  If you assuming 10pA leakage current, 0.1uF capacitors, and 0.01V allowable droop, you would have to refresh the voltage on each channel every 100 seconds.  You can probably get to usable time intervals if you can relax the allowable droop and/or increase the capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to take the voltage coming off a single pot and route it to the control voltage input of both filters, or to however many filters you're switching among. No need for even dual-gang. If the control voltages need to be different for the filters at the same knob setting, you can use op-amps to scale and bias the voltage at each input.